# Is there any tutorial on writing custom tikz decorations?

Tags: tikz-pgf, decorations, tutorials

I'd like to code a new decoration for TikZ.  Is there any tutorial, howto, manual or anything on the web, or should I just study the source?

Comment: The manual is pretty comprehensive though

Comment: But does it say anything about making your own decorations?

Comment: Yes, that's actually where I learned all of it. If you have a specific example we can work it out together

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is a whole section in the manual explaining how `\pgfdeclaredecoration` works, with vivid examples.

Comment: OP here, agreed. Should I just delete it?